# RESTful design pattern in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I'm designing an application trying to follow the REST spec.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to design it.

So let's say I'm doing a POST call that so I have a "post" method in my controller and model

```
// in controller
function post()
{
    //call post model here
}
```

In my post request I need to make the following checks:

```
-validate fields
-make sure item name is unique for that user
-make sure there are less than 10 items
-etc (there could be more cases)
```

Now in controller post function I will return a REST message and status code based on whatever happens, which is fine, but I'm curious to know where it's better to keep all those checks.

I can put all the checks in the model and then return some kind of array like:

```
array('text' => 'return response text/array or whatever here', 'code' => '200/400/etc')
```

Then just return this in the controller, or is it better to break up those checks into individual functions within the model and then do all the checks in the controller?

```
// in controller
function post()
{
    //if validation fails -> send response
    //if name is not unique -> send response
    //etc...
}
```

From a design point of view, if I ever wanted to potentially call the "post" method in the project model from other methods, it would not have an all encompassing function to handle it, however if I do keep it all in one model function it doesn't give me a lot of reusability.  If I had to pick sides, chances are I probably wouldn't need to reuse those "check functions" too much anyway, however it also seems weird to have all that response info in the model rather than the controller.

Can anyone please give me some input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not create post method inside the model (although having it in the controller is perfectly fine) simply because you just put code/model in such a frame that is not re-usable plus less readable. For instance, instead of post method in the model I would create `create` method.

There is no one-fits-all way for data validation. I like creating validation classes which have only one method `validate` for various data types (e.g. username validation class checks if it matches regex and is unique). It's better than copy pasting the validation code to every action (DRY). Where to call this class method? It depends. You can simply call that it in the action. Since the validation code is inside the validation class, it will look alright. You can also create a mapper which takes the request, determines what validations have to be performed and etc. but it might be overkill and is hard to do properly (maintainability wise).

For output again - DRY. It depends on what MVC framework are you using and there might be a good solution for this already. If not, you can create a class for that (yup, I am DRY maniac). You pass response code, array (or string) with response and class nicely wraps everything into JSON, XML format. Advantages: if you change then output format then you need to change only in one place.

Also consider using [Remote Facade](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html) pattern.

Hopefully, you found something useful in this post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this gave me some ideas.  I'm using codeigniter, so I just stuck all those cases into a custom validation class and that pretty much solved it.  Keeps everything DRY and keeps my controllers and models clean.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the API from the MVC application and use [Apify](http://www.apifydoc.com/)